# Moving a past commit to another branch

Tags: git, github

I have made a commit on a wrong branch and I wanted to know if I can move the commit from the branch to another.

Here's my actual situation

```
Branch 1 ----- 2 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6
              /   
HEAD ------- 1  
              \
Branch 2 ----- 3
```

And here is what i would have

```
Branch 1 ------ 4 --- 5 --- 6
              /   
HEAD ------- 1  
              \
Branch 2 ----- 2 --- 3
```

Is that even possible?

The commit "2" only add a file never used in that branch after but i need that file in my Branch 2.. Can I "simply" recreate the file in my Branch 2 and deal with the one my Branch 1 when I'm gonna merge them?
I'm using GitHub to host my code and GitKraken on my desktop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two option. Rebase or cherry-pick and revert.

Cherry-pick and revert is the simplest option and will have the least impact on your team. The history will not match your graphs exactly but will have the desired result

```
git checkout branch_1
git revert 2
git checkout branch_2
git cherry-pick 2
```

Rebase will give you the desired history but if you're working with other people could cause issues if they are working off the current history.

```
git checkout branch_1
git rebase -i 1
*Remove commit 2 from editor, save and quit*
git checkout branch_2
git rebase -i --root
*Remove commit 2 from editor, save and quit*
```